# How can I access the ListViewItems of a WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, internals

Within an event, I'd like to put the focus on a specific TextBox within the ListViewItem's template. The XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Focus this! -->
                        <TextBox x:Name="myBox"/>
```

I've tried the following in the code behind:

```
(myList.FindName("myBox") as TextBox).Focus();
```

but I seem to have misunderstood the `FindName()` docs, because it returns `null`.

Also the `ListView.Items` doesn't help, because that (of course) contains my bound business objects and no ListViewItems.

Neither does `myList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item)`, which also returns null.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To understand why `ContainerFromItem` didn't work for me, here some background. The event handler where I needed this functionality looks like this:

```
var item = new SomeListItem();
SomeList.Add(item);
ListViewItem = SomeList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item); // returns null
```

After the `Add()` the `ItemContainerGenerator` doesn't immediately create the container, because the `CollectionChanged` event could be handled on a non-UI-thread. Instead it starts an asynchronous call and waits for the UI thread to callback and execute the actual ListViewItem control generation.

To be notified when this happens, the `ItemContainerGenerator` exposes a `StatusChanged` event which is fired after all Containers are generated.

Now I have to listen to this event and decide whether the control currently want's to set focus or not.

Comment: This is definitely the answer. To add some info, I noticed that the event is invoked two times. The first time ContainerFromItem produces a null value, while the second time it returns the expected listviewitem object. This one saved my day!

Comment: This event is not exposed on WinRT

Comment: You can test for `itemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated` to know when the ListViewItems are ready.

Answer (score 15):

As others have noted, The myBox TextBox can not be found by calling FindName on the ListView.  However, you can get the ListViewItem that is currently selected, and use the VisualTreeHelper class to get the TextBox from the ListViewItem.  To do so looks something like this:

```
private void myList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        object o = myList.SelectedItem;
        ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)myList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(o);
        TextBox tb = FindByName("myBox", lvi) as TextBox;

        if (tb != null)
            tb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<bool>(tb.Focus));
    }
}

private FrameworkElement FindByName(string name, FrameworkElement root)
{
    Stack<FrameworkElement> tree = new Stack<FrameworkElement>();
    tree.Push(root);

    while (tree.Count > 0)
    {
        FrameworkElement current = tree.Pop();
        if (current.Name == name)
            return current;

        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            if (child is FrameworkElement)
                tree.Push((FrameworkElement)child);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Believe it or not, this has helped me with something unrelated that I've been trying to figure out. How to focus on the next textbox in a grid when the down key is pressed! So +1.

Comment: here's the post if you are interested: http://northdownsolutionslimited.co.uk/post/How-to-focus-on-the-next-row-textbox-in-a-WPF-DataGrid.aspx

Comment: The trouble with this is that - depending on *when* you're calling this - the `ViewItems` might not be created yet. Thus the necessity to listen for the `StatusChanged` event as described in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that the question title does not directly relate to the content of the question, and neither does the accepted answer answer it. I have been able to "access the ListViewItems of a WPF ListView" by using this:

```
public static IEnumerable<ListViewItem> GetListViewItemsFromList(ListView lv)
{
    return FindChildrenOfType<ListViewItem>(lv);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildrenOfType<T>(this DependencyObject ob)
    where T : class
{
    foreach (var child in GetChildren(ob))
    {
        T castedChild = child as T;
        if (castedChild != null)
        {
            yield return castedChild;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var internalChild in FindChildrenOfType<T>(child))
            {
                yield return internalChild;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildren(this DependencyObject ob)
{
    int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ob);

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        yield return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ob, i);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how hectic the recursion gets, but it seemed to work fine in my case. And no, I have not used `yield return` in a recursive context before.

Comment: The trouble with this is that - depending on *when* you're calling this - the `ViewItems` might not be created yet. Thus the necessity to listen for the `StatusChanged` event as described in my answer.

Comment: Thankyou! Worked "as is", and did exactly what I wanted. Nice work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse up the ViewTree to find the item '*ListViewItem*' record set that corresponds to the cell triggered from hit test.

Similarly, you can get the column headers from the parent view to compare and match the cell's column.  You may want to bind the cell name to the column header name as your key for your comparator delegate/filter.

For example:  HitResult is on TextBlock shown in green.   You wish to obtain the handle to the '*ListViewItem*'.

[image]

```
/// <summary>
///   ListView1_MouseMove
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void ListView1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (ListView1.Items.Count <= 0)
    return;

  // Retrieve the coordinate of the mouse position.
  var pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement) sender);

  // Callback to return the result of the hit test.
  HitTestResultCallback myHitTestResult = result => {
    var obj = result.VisualHit;

    // Add additional DependancyObject types to ignore triggered by the cell's parent object container contexts here.
    //-----------
    if (obj is Border)
      return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
    //-----------

    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj) as GridViewRowPresenter;
    if (parent == null)
      return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;

    var headers = parent.Columns.ToDictionary(column => column.Header.ToString());

    // Traverse up the VisualTree and find the record set.
    DependencyObject d = parent;
    do {
      d = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d);
    } while (d != null && !(d is ListViewItem));

    // Reached the end of element set as root's scope.
    if (d == null)
      return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;

    var item = d as ListViewItem;
    var index = ListView1.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
    Debug.WriteLine(index);

    lblCursorPosition.Text = $"Over {item.Name} at ({index})";

    // Set the behavior to return visuals at all z-order levels.
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
  };

  // Set up a callback to receive the hit test result enumeration.
  VisualTreeHelper.HitTest((Visual)sender, null, myHitTestResult, new PointHitTestParameters(pt));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We use a similar technique with WPF's new datagrid:

```
Private Sub SelectAllText(ByVal cell As DataGridCell)
    If cell IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim txtBox As TextBox= GetVisualChild(Of TextBox)(cell)
        If txtBox IsNot Nothing Then
            txtBox.Focus()
            txtBox.SelectAll()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetVisualChild(Of T As {Visual, New})(ByVal parent As Visual) As T
    Dim child As T = Nothing
    Dim numVisuals As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)
    For i As Integer = 0 To numVisuals - 1
        Dim v As Visual = TryCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i), Visual)
        If v IsNot Nothing Then
            child = TryCast(v, T)
            If child Is Nothing Then
                child = GetVisualChild(Of T)(v)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return child
End Function
```

The technique should be fairly applicable for you, just pass your listviewitem once it's generated.

Answer (score -1):

Or it can be simply done by

```
private void yourtextboxinWPFGrid_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //textbox can be catched like this. 
       var textBox = ((TextBox)sender);
       EmailValidation(textBox.Text);
    }
```