# Listview WPF : Add bg color programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, background

Hi I am trying to add color to bg of a listview item dynamically while runtime but I get the following exception.

Unable to cast object of type 'RootObject.Controls.ListItem' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem'.

My requirement is to check a condition while clicking a button and if the process is success change the bg to green else red. Here is my WPF code

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListView" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged" MouseDoubleClick="List_MouseDoubleClick"  SelectionMode="Single"/>
```

And here is my code behind,

```
if(RootVal.sendResult == true)
{                       
  foreach (ListViewItem item1 in ListView.Items)
      {
        item1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
      }
}
```

Comment: I immediately noticed this : `foreach (ListViewItem item1 in ListView.Items)`. Is your ListView named `ListView`?

Comment: Also, are you populating the ListView with custom controls?

Comment: Obviously `Items` contains collection of `RootObject.Controls.ListItem` rather than `System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem`. Show where you set `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`.

Comment: @TimothyGroote The Name is set custom I changed it here thinking it might be confusing. And yes I am populating with custom controls

Comment: @Maxim  Here is the code..     private ObservableList<ListItem> ListOfItems= new ObservableList<ListItem>(); ListView.ItemsSource = ListOfItems;

Comment: Regardless of what you populated your ListView with, why not just use `foreach (var item1 in ListView.Items)`? C# will take care of the rest.

Comment: Take a look at type of the objects in `Items` collection in debugger and say us what do you see.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Tried it already..  But this will throw an compile error that object contains no definition for background

Comment: So why do you expect `ListViewItem` in `Items` if you have collection of `ListItem` there? Title of the question is completely wrong, your problem doesn't related with setting of background.

Comment: @Sanga Sounds like you need to modify your control `ListItem` to implement the `Background` field.

Comment: @Maxim  Yes sorry.. got it now...Now Trying to access and set property through Datatemplate binding.. Thanks all.. Have a nice day..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Items` property of the ListView does *not* contain controls, it contains your (view)models. (the ones you set as the ItemsSource)

The proper way of going about this MVVM style would be to bind the background color from the `DataTemplate` of the ListView to a property of your (view)model.

If you are still looking for a way to set the `ListViewItem`'s background color, take a look at [How can I access the ListViewItems of a WPF ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92328/how-can-i-access-the-listviewitems-of-a-wpf-listview)

(but be warned, they're not so easy to reach)

Comment: Note that `Items` contains view models only if your item presenters created dynamically with `ItemsSource`. You can populate `ListView` by `ListViewItem`'s explicitly and then `Items` will contain collection of `ListViewItem`.

Comment: @Maxim Yes.. Its created dynamically with itemsource... hopefully this works.. Thanks..