# How to access ListView item's name in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView and I want to access TextBox's item name in a method to change its visibility on mouse click event. How can I do it? Because it is not accessible.

```
<ListView Name="currentTasks"> 
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <WrapPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
              <TextBox Name="taskTextBox" Visibility="hidden"/>
           </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**SOLUTION**

Alright, I found out the solution. If you have similar problem then here is the link with the answer that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/92765/17195987

Comment: There are several ways, either you save the objects during the creation in a list or you ask "currentTasks" for his items, that you do with `currentTasks.Items`.

Comment: It's better and easier to follow the MVVM pattern (i.e. binding) instead of accessing the view by name in this case.